# Problems installing Java EE SDK on Linux

Tags: java, linux, installation, sh

I installed the Java 6 JRE on my VPS just fine, but I can't get the EE SDK installation to even run.

```
root@vps [/usr/java]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

However, when I try to run `java_ee_sdk-6-unix.sh`:

```
./  ../  java_ee_sdk-6-unix.sh*  jre1.6.0_18/  jre.bin*
root@vps [/usr/java]# ./java_ee_sdk-6-unix.sh

Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system
and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME
```

But the catch is that I set my environment variables correctly:

```
root@vps [/usr/java]# echo $PATH
/usr/java/jre1.6.0_18:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_18/bin:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_18/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
root@vps [/usr/java]# export -p | grep JAVA_HOME
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.6.0_18"
```

I'm pulling my hair out here, any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't your distro have a package manager? Why don't you use that?

Comment: I don't think I can get the EE SDK via rpm. http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp - Sun just hands it out as a .sh installation.

Comment: What does  "which jar"   say?

Comment: It says nothing. Same with whereis jar.

Comment: Fix that - put jar on the path and then see if your installer works.

Comment: If you have none, you should install a JRE to get one (SE)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you have a JDK installed? You likely want to put `$JDK_HOME/bin` on your PATH, not the `/bin` of a JRE, as `jar` comes with JDK, not JRE.

Answer (score 7):

Do this:

1. Delete all installations of Java.
2. Install the [Java SDK](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) (self-extracting) into **/opt/jdk1.6.0_16** (for example)
3. Create a symbolic link: `ln -s /opt/jdk1.6.0_16 /opt/jdk`
4. Edit `$HOME/.bashrc`:

   JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
5. Logout and log back in.

This offers many advantages:

- You can install multiple versions of the SDK and need only switch a symbolic link.
- You know where all the files are located.
- You know exactly which version of Java is being used.
- No other versions are installed, so there cannot be any conflicts.

I have done this for years and have never had any problems with Java on Linux, except for packages that do not detect that Java is installed and attempt to install the OpenJDK.

Also, stay away from the OpenJDK as its fonts are terrible to behold.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty solution for me:

```
sudo apt-get install jarwrapper fastjar
```

Then just run your .sh script and voila!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. I removed OpenJDK using apt-get (I'm running Ubuntu 11.10) then downloaded Java JDK 1.7 (which comes of course with JRE) and unpacked this under /usr/local/java - this gave me new directory:

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04
```

Next I added:

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04
```

to $PATH, set $JAVA_HOME and $JRE_HOME as

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre
```

respectively.

Everything works nice. I can compile java progams using **javac** and run them using **java**. **Jar** program runs fine as well. So why does java ee installer complain about that? Any clues as how to fix that?

Comment: problem is not valid anymore, the problem was I tried to run the installer as **sudo bash java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh**, I just swiched to root account using su and it works! :D

Comment: Of course it's because root has different $PATH var. After switching to root user you must add $JAVA_HOME (it's necessary to set this var once again) to $PATH (PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME).

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem, however it was related to the sudo user account when executing the .sh file.
I was installing Glassfish v3 on a new VPS hosted server with Ubuntu 10.4 64Bit OS.

```
sudo chmod +x java_ee_sdk-6u2-jdk-linux-x64.sh

sudo ./java_ee_sdk-6u2-jdk-linux-x64.sh -s -a java_ee_sdk-6u2-jdk-linux-x64-install-answers.txt
```

Only to get the exact same error you were first experiencing:

```
Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system
and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME
```

Silly really, when I ran the command like this:

```
  ./java_ee_sdk-6u2-jdk-linux-x64.sh -s -a java_ee_sdk-6u2-jdk-linux-x64-install-answers.txt
```

To my suprise it responded with:

```
Welcome to GlassFish V3 installer

Using the user defined JAVA_HOME : /opt/jdk
Entering setup...
```

This was after I had setup my JAVA_HOME in file: `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had jdk1.6.0_16 extracted in my home directory and had a symbolic links to `java` and `/javac` in `/bin`.  Then I encountered the error described above in the question.

However once I included a symbolic link to `jar` in `/bin`, the shell script to install Java EE ran as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This info works for me... The first method was enought.

Regards.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11485538#post11485538

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents...

I have the same problem and solve it by installing a jar utility.

As **"matt b"** said the problem was (well my problem), that the installer was not finding a jar utility (jar program), needed to run the installation files.

> Do you have a JDK installed? You likely want to put $JDK_HOME/bin on your PATH, not the /bin of a JRE, as jar comes with JDK, not JRE.

But in my case (having Ubuntu 11.10 x64 and JAVA_HOME --> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk) the problem was not fixed by setting the JDK/bin dir on the PATH. Instead I had to install a jar utility package (using Synaptic) called Jarwrapper version 0.37ubuntu1.

After installing it, the installation script of Oracle's JDK (java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-linux-x64-ml.sh) ran just fine.

Regards,