# Error! How to install GlassFish in Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I try to install [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) on Ubuntu, and I get the error:

> Could not locate a suitable jar
>   utility. Please ensure that you have
>   Java 6 or newer installed on your
>   system and accessible in your PATH or
>   by setting JAVA_HOME

when I type

> echo $PATH

it prints out:

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:**/opt/jdk1.6.0_20**:/opt/jdk1.6.0_20/bin

Where is the problem and how to solve it?

I have also read "[Problems installing Java EE SDK on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224321/problems-installing-java-ee-sdk-on-linux)", but it doesn't work.

N.B. Before reinstalling Ubuntu it works fine. This problem comes after reinstallation.

Comment: What is the value of ´$JAVA_HOME´?

Comment: Also, how did you install it? If you got Glassfish from the official website, try to install from packages instead.

Comment: Also, on the command line, type `javac`. That should be found, though it will return an error because there are no input files. If it is not found, check whether there is something in /opt/jdk1.6.0_20/bin.

Comment: Is Java installed correctly? What happens if you run the command `jar`, or `java` or `javac`?

Comment: If i type javac, it also works.

Comment: The terminal sees every command from java

Comment: Does `java -version` show the right version of Java?

Comment: yes. I tried to download glassfish from other sources, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to user permissions. I think I tried to install GlassFish without enough rights.

Answer (score 3):

if you follow this tutorial you should be fine and all you problems will be gone:
http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-301-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have */opt/jdk1.6.0_20* in your PATH and the *java* executables are located in */opt/jdk1.6.0_20/bin*. The best way is to define JAVA_HOME environment variable that contains */opt/jdk1.6.0_20* string and add $JAVA_HOME/bin to PATH variable.

Comment: OK. So could you check if files like java, javac, etc. in /opt/jdk1.6.0_20/bin have executable permissions? And the user that GlassFish is running on, has necessary permissions to JDK directory and subdirectories?
If yes, then what do you get when you type: java -version while being logged into the GlassFish user account?

Comment: Yes! All have executable permissions.
And when I check for java version:

~$ java -version
it gets:

java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)