# Linux (Ubuntu) Java plugin and console

Tags: java, linux, firefox, ubuntu, applet

I'm trying to test a Java applet in Firefox in Ubuntu 10.10. Unfortunately it doesn't work out of the box. I have two issues:

1. <s>By default the IcedTea plugin was used, which I don't trust. I installed `sun-java6-plugin` but have no idea which one is used by Firefox (and other browsers) now. How can I make sure?</s> *Fixed this by simply removing icedtea.*
2. I have no console. It's usually accessible via a tray icon in Windows, but not here (<s>maybe this will automatically be fixed by #1 though</s> *No it wasn't*). There's [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5403/) but it doesn't work anymore.
   **Update:** I've sort of fixed this by going to the Java control panel and checking "Show Console" in the advanced tab, but now the console always pops up which isn't quite perfect yet.

I'm deploying the applet via JNLP. You can see it [here](http://game.dreambear.nl/viewstats), if it helps. I have `sun-java6-jdk` as the default Java.

(Sorry if this question belongs on SuperUser or another site, but I figured that with #2 especially this is a programming related question)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.blog.highub.com/linux/install-java-on-ubuntu-firefox/)

Comment: @org.life.java: Thanks, but that's what I already did (except with version 6 of course)

Comment: To install the correct JRE, you have to enable first the extra software sources in `software-properties-gtk` (run as sudo), second tab. Then you can find the official JRE in Synaptic.

Comment: Is there a question left? What isn't perfect yet?

Comment: @Martijn: The console always opens, for every applet. Even when I'm not interested in it, or for real world applets that I didn't make and am not trying to test.

Answer (score 1):

With :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/64/jre1.6.0_20/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/64/jre1.6.0_20/bin/java
```

You can set the default jre (in this case a 64 bits one)

with:

```
java -version
```

you can see the version

With [about:plugins](http://about%3aplugins) you can see which jre firefox is using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224321/problems-installing-java-ee-sdk-on-linux/2224528#2224528