# Why do I need Java installed to install the JavaEE6 SDK?

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, sdk, java

New on Linux, I try to install the JavaEE 6 SDK, first step to install GlassFFish:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u4-jdk-7u11-downloads-1900532.html

When I run

```
sh java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux-x64.sh
```

on my server, I get prompted that I should have Java installed:

```
Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system
and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME
```

This is where I am confused:

- is it the Java from the JDK package? But I am in the process of installing it, so of course I don't have it installed yet!
- is it the Java from the JRE then? Should I install it first (and set up the environment variables etc.)?

Thx for any clarification!

Comment: If you want to execute Java code, you need the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) a.k.a. JRE. If you want to develop in Java (whatever kind of application), you need the Java Development Kit a.k.a. JDK. The Java EE SDK (GlassFish) will depend on the JDK to work, similar with other tools like Android SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems installing Java EE SDK on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224321/problems-installing-java-ee-sdk-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use any java code, including Java Development Kit, JDK, you'll need to have Java Runtime Environment, JRE. Most of the JDK package comes with JRE. JRE contains API to run Java classes.